# Reverse tunneling

Tags: ssh

i want to visit my xampp localhost from my server ip. my broadband internet provider does not allow me to forward any port so i need to do reverse tunneling. so if some one visit 216.158.xxx.xxx:27272 (my vps ip  is 216.158.xxx.xxx) he/she will see my pc contents of 127.0.0.1:27272

i m using putty on my pc and centos 7 on my vps server.

i try to configure putty by going to ssh tunnel 
source:27272
destination: 127.0.0.1:27272

its not working

i have set GatewayPorts yes on my vps

EDIT: I have fixed this problem

Comment: Have you chosen "remote" instead of "local" in tunnel - settings in Putty?

Comment: Yes i have chosen remote.

Comment: What happens if you do the following on a console on your VPS? wget http://127.0.0.1:27272

Comment: --2016-10-24 19:03:54--  http://127.0.0.1:27272/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:27272... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20700 (20K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

100%[======================================>] 20,700      66.3KB/s   in 0.3s

2016-10-24 19:03:56 (66.3 KB/s) - 'index.html' saved [20700/20700]


Thank you so much  :) is it ok?

Comment: i found my localhost index page on the server root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the port 27272 on your VPS. If it has a static IP-address configuring the firewall might be enough. This gives everybody public access.

Comment: i have turned off firewall of my vps using csf -x command. and im seeing this on my vps netstat

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27272           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: Thankssss a lottttt . it works now after disabling firewall of my vps

Comment: Be aware that disabling the whole firewall gives people more possibilities than probably needed.